# Export a Gateway object through soma script in datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have 50 MPGW's, i want to export specific/individual gateway through soma script.I tried few scripta but didnt worked out. I tried domain export it is working but specific objecf export is not working.Please help me on it

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and what happened when you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple, really, you just need to point out the objects you want to export, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <dp:request xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
      <dp:do-export format="ZIP" all-files="false">
        <dp:user-comment>This is a SOMA Export...</dp:user-comment>
        <dp:object class="MultiProtocolGateway" name="MPGW_1" ref-objects="true" ref-files="true"/>
        <dp:object class="MultiProtocolGateway" name="MPGW_2" ref-objects="true" ref-files="true"/>
      </dp:do-export>
    </dp:request>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer